# Looking for Python code for built in list functions

Tags: python, list, function, built-in

Where can I find the actual code of Python's list built-in commands? For example list.remove() or list.index().

I've attempted to create my own version of the built-in methods but with Python, for loops, the increment value is used to hold the array index.

Comment: [list.remove](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Objects/listobject.c#L2605), [list.index](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Objects/listobject.c#L2540).

Comment: `import math math.__file_` use this you can get lib path where you can show built-in code.

Comment: @soheshdoshi: For functions in native code, that will just show you the compiled library, which is likely not what is being asked about.

Answer (score 1):

Python is open-source language.

You can find everything that you want on the GitHub: https://github.com/python

If you need sources for the concrete version of the Python, you can download it from Python site: https://www.python.org/downloads/source/

Comment: "If you need sources for the concrete version of the Python, you can download"... or select the tag you want on GitHub.